# Javascript global variables issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below snippet doesn't get me the value of the global var id displayed in my console. Where am I going wrong?

```
var id;

function set_id(myid){
 id=myid;
}

function get_id(){
 return id;
}

$("#btn").click(function(){
 $.post("....", function(data){ //data reurns a JSON
  set_id(id); //success!!
 }
}

$("#show").click(function()[
 console.log(get_id()); //doesn't work, how do I get this workin.. Where am I going wrong
}
```

Comment: It must print something on the console. What?

Comment: Are you trying to return the global variable id in get_id()? try console.log(id) in $("#show").click()

Comment: Works http://jsfiddle.net/Kirrr/vMBkZ/

Comment: "Doesn't work" is mean nothing, we always get back results, maybe not the ones we expected. So, what actually `console.log(get_id())` returns? Also, in `set_id` you set a variable called `id`, that is the have the same name of the global ones, so it could be that you're [shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the global ones multiple times, or maybe you didn't declare the local ones redeclared the global ones again. You also have a typo `function()[` instead of `function(){`, if this is the actually code you will have a syntax error on your error console.

Answer (score 3):

Why would you use global variable and getters/setters? You can set it anywhere since it GLOBAL:

```
id = x;
```

and get it anywhere:

```
x = id;
```

So your code would be:

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
    $.post("....", function(data) {
        id = data.id;
    });
});

$("#show").click(function() {
    console.log(id);
});
```

Comment: Thx for correcting syntax :) I've just copied author's code.

Answer (score 1):

This code looks suspicious to me:

```
$("#show").click(function()[
   console.log(get_id()); //doesn't work, how do I get this workin.. Where am I going   wrong
}
```

Maybe you meant this:

```
$("#show").click(function(){
   console.log(get_id());
});
```

Comment: If errors in his working script were such that, the first button would not work too

Comment: Yeah, I saw that the first jQuery usage was also not correctly ended. But this had a squared bracket, not a curly one. It's a bigger problem, I think.

Answer (score 0):

your syntax is wrong.  `[` just before the console.log

Comment: Its syntax is also not enough `)` after both `click`